# Email send using SES(AWS) service in nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-sns

I am trying to send email from **AWS SES service using nodemailer in node js**.

I am getting error "Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check-in region US-EAST-1:"

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var sesTransport = require('nodemailer-ses-transport');

var SESCREDENTIALS = {
    accessKeyId : "XXX" ,
    secretAccessKey : "XXX"
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(sesTransport({
    accessKeyId: SESCREDENTIALS.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: SESCREDENTIALS.secretAccessKey,
    rateLimit: 5,
    serverUrl : 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
}));

var mailOptions = {
    from: 'FromName <no-reply@domain.com>',
    to: 'daiyabhagyashree@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Amazon SES Template TesT', // Subject line
    html: '<p>Mail message</p>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if( error ) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info);
    }
});
```

Please suggest me the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to verify the email address to send emails.

[Verifying an Email Address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses-procedure.html)
[Amazon SES Email Sending Errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ses-errors.html)

> You are trying to send email from an email address or domain that you
>   have not verified with Amazon SES. This error could apply to the
>   "From", "Source", "Sender", or "Return-Path" address. If your account
>   is still in the Amazon SES sandbox, you also must verify every
>   recipient email address except for the recipients provided by the
>   Amazon SES mailbox simulator. If Amazon SES is not able to show all of
>   the failed identities, the error message ends with an ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ses-errors.html

*Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region region: identity1, identity2, identity3—You are trying to send email from an email address or domain that you have not verified with Amazon SES. This error could apply to the "From", "Source", "Sender", or "Return-Path" address. If your account is still in the Amazon SES sandbox, you also must verify every recipient email address except for the recipients provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator. If Amazon SES is not able to show all of the failed identities, the error message ends with an ellipsis.
Note
Amazon SES has endpoints in multiple AWS Regions, and email address verification status is separate for each AWS Region. You must complete the verification process for each sender in the AWS Region(s) you want to use.*